# How to queue up REST requests / halt processing on an REST endpoint for sometime without losing the requests?

Tags: java, rest, web-services

I have 2 rest endpoints in my application. I have a requirement to halt processing on the first endpoint when the second one is being invoked. I would like to process the requests later when the second processing is complete. How is this achievable in java? I am using [Java -Spark](http://sparkjava.com/) libraries. Any thoughts / leads will be highly appreciated!

Comment: Use a lock, and make sure the request queue of the socket and/or servlet container is large enough to store the pending requests. --- And decide what to do with endpoint 1 requests in progress when endpoint 2 request arrives.

Comment: hmm, I thought of this initially. I was wondering if there some standard way to this.

Answer (score 0):

why not create 2 bools to check if they're active and just flip one off when the condition you're looking for is met.